# Unable to upload document to Dropbox using setFilesToUpload() in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to use `setFilesToUpload()` method to upload documents to Dropbox using TestCafe.

I have already tried a few things, but without any luck:

- tried with visibility to false for the input locators
- tried to look for various locators but which can take input

Has anyone face similar issue? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @pavelsaman

my code looks like this
    await t.setFilesToUpload(
      Selector('input[type="file"]', { visibilityCheck: false }),
      '../data/me.jpg',
    );

the DOM structure look like this

<input type="file" multiple="" style="display: none;" data-upload-kit-id="0">
<input type="file" webkitdirectory="" style="display: none;">

There is not element to `click` save/open button since the upload occurs when select document from local file system and click open.

Answer (score 0):

Your test code looks correct. It may be unclear that the file was actually uploaded. To confirm that, you can check the input element's `value` property. Here's an example test:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fileUpload`.page `./index.html`;

test('fileUpload', async t => {
    const input = Selector('input[type="file"]', { visibilityCheck: false });

    await t.setFilesToUpload(input, ['./img.jpg'])
        .expect(input.value).eql('C:\\fakepath\\img.jpg');
})
```

There is a recipe for uploading files on [the TestCafe website](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html).